# UISearchController with UITableView ui glitch

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am implementing a UISearchController with a UITableView and as you can see in the video, when starting to type in the search bar the transition of the UISearchBar is not smooth and the UITableView goes over it (at the beginning of the gif).

[image]

I am using UIViewController with a UITableView.
I read that it may be related to constraints, I am setting the UITableView top to safe area's top and adding the UISearchController programatically as you can see here:

```
private let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
searchController.searchBar.accessibilityTraits = .searchField
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Xcode 11.5, iOS 13 and Swift 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced many of these issues myself too. Each time a new version of iOS releases many of the subtle animations breaks, leading to a bad user experience. Here's what I did to reduce my issues although it didn't fix all of them, hope this helps you too. Here's what I did:

Initially, I was using a `ViewController` that inherits from `UIViewController` and containing `UITableView` in it constraining all 4 sides. I replaced this with a `UITableViewController` instead of the `UIViewController`.